# Return to same page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I try to upload a file. But if the user doesnt select a file, the same page has to been seen with a message that you have to upload a file.

I have this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult UploadFile([Bind(Include = "UploadData,Directories")] /*LibraryUploadModel libraryUpload*/ UploadViewModel uploadViewModel, string designId, string folder, FormLibraryEntry formLibraryEntry, string command)
{
    //ActionResultSpecification result = SfsHelpers.GeneralHelper.HandleLibraryOverwrite(formLibraryEntry.Guid, this, command, FormRootPath, customerSchema, LibraryMode.FormLibrary);
    try
    {
        if ((uploadViewModel.UploadData != null) && (uploadViewModel.UploadData.ContentLength > 0) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(uploadViewModel.UploadData.FileName))
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadViewModel.UploadData.FileName);
            TemplateLibraryEntry entry = GetTemplateLibraryEntry(designId, customerSchema);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/"), entry.FilePath, folder.Replace('/', '\\').Trim('\\'), fileName);
            uploadViewModel.UploadData.SaveAs(path);
        }
        else
            return Json(new { Message = "Error in saving file, Go back and  try again" });
            // return RedirectToAction("UploadFile");
            //return View(uploadViewModel);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

But now the json message is shown. The name of the page where you can upload is UploadFile.

I have it now like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult UploadFile([Bind(Include = "UploadData,Directories")] /*LibraryUploadModel libraryUpload*/ UploadViewModel uploadViewModel, string designId, string folder, FormLibraryEntry formLibraryEntry, string command)
{
    //ActionResultSpecification result = SfsHelpers.GeneralHelper.HandleLibraryOverwrite(formLibraryEntry.Guid, this, command, FormRootPath, customerSchema, LibraryMode.FormLibrary);
    try
    {
        if ((uploadViewModel.UploadData != null) && (uploadViewModel.UploadData.ContentLength > 0) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(uploadViewModel.UploadData.FileName))
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadViewModel.UploadData.FileName);
            TemplateLibraryEntry entry = GetTemplateLibraryEntry(designId, customerSchema);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/"), entry.FilePath, folder.Replace('/', '\\').Trim('\\'), fileName);
            uploadViewModel.UploadData.SaveAs(path);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("uploadViewModel", "your message");
            return View(uploadViewModel);
        }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }          
}
```

and the view like this:

```
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
    <table>
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Directories.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <fieldset>
                        <input type="radio" name="folder" value="@Model.Directories[i]" id="folder(@i)">
                        <label for="folder(@i)">@Model.Directories[i]</label>
                    </fieldset>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

but the problem is that if you press on Uploaden without an upload file, I get this error:

```
Line 55:                                 <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
Line 56:                                     <table>
Line 57:                                         @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Directories.Count; i++)
Line 58:                                         {
Line 59:                                             <tr>

Source File: b:\Seneca\Producten\FormsServer\Trunk\SenecaFormsServer\Areas\Dashboard\Views\DesignTemplate\UploadFile.cshtml    Line: 57
```

and the directories are null: Model.Directories = null

Comment: Your need to return the `View` You could add the message to a `ViewBag` property (using view model would be better) and access the message in the view.

Comment: And in addition to mattytommo's answer, it needs to be `ModelState.AddModelError("", "your message");` to display in the validation summary, or the first parameter needs to be the name of a property (and I suspect `uploadViewModel` is not a property name)

Comment: And you need to show you model so we can understand how to correct your view.

Comment: And since you don' appear to be creating any controls for `Directories` then they wont be posted back. You need to repopulate the collection before you return the view.

Comment: Thank you. But how ro repopulate the directories? I try it like this:  uploadViewModel.Directories = new List<string>();

Comment: The same way you initially populated it in the GET method.

Comment: @StephenMuecke If he re-populates he won't see the changes as he's returning the same view (because of `ModelState`)

Comment: @mattytommo, OP is not binding to any properties of `Directory` for editing - it appears they just used as a choice/option (radio button group) for binding to a property with the name `folder` - `<input type="radio" name="folder" value="@Model.Directories[i] ... />`

Comment: Thank you Stehen. It was a combination of the action method and the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that you are binding your `Directories` to your view, but the name attribute of your radio button isn't correctly formed so it won't be posted to the server. Subsequently, when you send the view back with the model that property will be null. Whilst you're at it, use `LabelFor` as well.

Change it to the following:

```
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Directories.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <fieldset>
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Directories, Model.Directories[i])
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Directories[i])
                </fieldset>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but now all the radiobuttons are selected, and I have as output:Directories[0]..etc

Comment: @DimitriEngelen Apologies, my `RadioButtonFor` declaration was slightly incorrect, try my updated edit.